# Parsing Gmail Labels into tree structure

Tags: python, parsing, tree, directory, gmail

For those who don't know. If you have a gmail account, you can make various "folders" in your gmail account called labels. Now all these really are - are just a list of values with a name (its not actually a tree structure)

```
family
family/finance
```

However, Gmail will under the hood parse this into a tree structure.

[image]

The online gmail API will only return a list similar to what we have on the left

```
['family','family/eat/me','family/finance']
```

I want to parse this into a structure like

```
[{'name':'family','parent':None,'children':['family/eat/me','family/finance']},
 {'name':'family/eat/me','parent':'family','children':[]},
 {'name':'family/finance','parent':'family','children':[]}]
```

However, I am really stumped, anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Me too, I would like to know how to do it efficiently!!! :)